# Problemas en Laravel al iniciar sesion

Tags: php, laravel, spatie, laravel-9

estoy subiendo mi primera aplicacion laravel a un hosting, y luego de crear un usuario, me sale el siguiente error:

[image: Esta pantalla me sale al darle a crear usuario]

Estoy viendo que a el registro del nuevo usuario me lo creó.

[image: Así tengo mi proyecto dividido]

Mi proyecto esta en la carpeta dash_roles test, mientras que todo lo que estaba en public, lo puse en la carpeta public_html.

Aclaro que el proyecto está con laravel 9, ya verifiqué que en mi servidor este seleccionada la misma version de PHP con la cual hice el proyecto. Modifique las lineas en el archivo index.php ubicada en public_html.

Si necesitan que suba algo mas para que puedan encontrar donde se encuentra el error, me avisan y lo subo.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que comentas de la carpeta public_html y que has dejado fuera tu proyecto, pero en teoría todo el proyecto de laravel tendría que estar en public_html

Comment: entiendo que no. Lei en todos lados que no. se crea una carpeta paralela, al mismo nivel que el public_html, y se pasa ahi dentro

Comment: Te falta subir ese archivo `mix-manifest.json` y probablemente los assets css y js

Comment: Lamentablemente eera ese el problema porloscerros, pero no se porque me demandaba ese archivo, sino use Vue en ningun momento. Simplemente elimine las dos lineas que me solicitaban ese archivo y ahora anda a la perfeccion. Saludos